# tail: /var/log/snmpd.log: Operation not supported on socket

Tags: command-line, logs

*OS: MacOS Catalina*

I've already tried kill -s INT `syslogd` and `logd` and also loading and unloading `snmpd` but still cannot open the file:

```
cat /var/log/snmpd.log 
cat: /var/log/snmpd.log: Connection refused
```

File shows in green with an equal sign (first time ever I see this):

[image]

However I don't think I have any process writing to that file other than snmpd and I stopped it.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? I ran a `netstat` but cannot really figure anything out of it.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a file, it's a socket, used for interprocess communication. It's probably connected to some sort of log-management daemon. See https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-are-unix-sockets-and-how-do-they-work/

Comment: @GordonDavisson is, I am sure, correct in this instance.  But on my Mac (macOS 14.3.1 running the snmp daemon) it is a regular file created at last boot time which I can view (everyone: readonly) whilst the daemon is active.

Comment: Oooh, that's interesting, thanks @GordonDavisson! I was under the impression sockets had .sock extension, but this clarifies a lot.

Comment: @Gilby: Yessir, that's how my OS behaves as well, however I cannot view it under any circumstances, not even stopping snmpd daemon, so I believe the socket explanation is much more appropiate in this case?

Comment: Not sure what you expect to read from a socket if no process is writing to it. But anyway, can you please run `ls -l /var/log/snmpd.log` and add the result to the question, **as text**.